# Pandas to Excel - make part of the text bold

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to make part of the string/cell bold in Pandas? I'm working with plenty of textual data, exporting to Excel and then using it in Word as linked content, so I can't format it after it gets exported since the data changes pretty often.

Simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["Hello world."], ["Hello bold world."]], columns = ["example"])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('sample.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sample', index=False)
writer.save()
```

I want to make "bold" in bold. Is there a way or another way how to highlight just part of the string?

I've tested using `**bold**`, `<b>bold</b>`, `'\033[1mbold\033[0m'` but no success at all.

Thanks a lot

Comment: maybe this will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591557/color-part-of-text-in-cell-with-pandas-excelwriter

Comment: Aww! Thanks a lot, it pushed me in the right direction and solved this awful trouble. Posting my solution bellow in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @NoobVB I was pointed in the right direction: `write_rich_string`. Found this [great article](https://devdreamz.com/question/129769-write-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-with-xlsxwriter-and-include-write-rich-string) describing it as a cookbook and turned it into a working solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.excel._xlsxwriter import XlsxWriter


class RichExcelWriter(XlsxWriter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RichExcelWriter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _value_with_fmt(self, val):
        if type(val) == list:
            return val, None
        return super(RichExcelWriter, self)._value_with_fmt(val)

    def _write_cells(self, cells, sheet_name=None, startrow=0, startcol=0, freeze_panes=None):
        sheet_name = self._get_sheet_name(sheet_name)
        if sheet_name in self.sheets:
            wks = self.sheets[sheet_name]
        else:
            wks = self.book.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
            #add handler to the worksheet when it's created
            wks.add_write_handler(list, lambda worksheet, row, col, list, style: worksheet._write_rich_string(row, col, *list))
            self.sheets[sheet_name] = wks
        super(RichExcelWriter, self)._write_cells(cells, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes)

writer = RichExcelWriter('sample.xlsx')
workbook = writer.book
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

df = pd.DataFrame([["Hello world."], [["Hello", bold, "bold", "world."]]], columns = ["example"])

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sample', index=False)
writer.save()
```

This is the easiest way I figured out so far.

Answer (score 0):

The update by Karolína Vyskočilová and Bruno Henrique is super. The only problem was it deleted spaces between words from the original df.
I slightly modified it to work with the parts of the keywords from the list.
Here is the result

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.excel._xlsxwriter import XlsxWriter
from openpyxl.styles import Font
import re

class RichExcelWriter(XlsxWriter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RichExcelWriter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _value_with_fmt(self, val):
        if type(val) == list:
            return val, None
        return super(RichExcelWriter, self)._value_with_fmt(val)

    def _write_cells(self, cells, sheet_name=None, startrow=0, startcol=0, freeze_panes=None):
        sheet_name = self._get_sheet_name(sheet_name)
        if sheet_name in self.sheets:
            wks = self.sheets[sheet_name]
        else:
            wks = self.book.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
            wks.add_write_handler(list, lambda worksheet, row, col, list, style: worksheet._write_rich_string(row, col, *list))
            self.sheets[sheet_name] = wks
        super(RichExcelWriter, self)._write_cells(cells, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes)

# Load the existing Excel document
input_file_path = "Test document.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(input_file_path)

# Define the words to be made bold
bold_words = ['news', 'post', 'retreat', 'retrato', "paper"]

# Define the bold font style
bold_font = Font(bold=True)

# Create a list to hold formatted rows
formatted_rows = []

# Iterate through each row in the DataFrame
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    formatted_row = []
    for cell_value in row:
        if isinstance(cell_value, str):
            formatted_cell_value = []
            words = re.findall(r'\S+|\s+', cell_value)
            for word in words:
                if word.strip() and any(bold_word in word for bold_word in bold_words):
                    formatted_cell_value.extend([bold, word])
                else:
                    formatted_cell_value.append(word)
            formatted_row.append(formatted_cell_value)
        else:
            formatted_row.append(cell_value)
    formatted_rows.append(formatted_row)

# Create a new DataFrame with the formatted rows
formatted_df = pd.DataFrame(formatted_rows, columns=df.columns)

# Save the modified Excel document
output_file_path = "updated_Test document.xlsx"
writer = RichExcelWriter(output_file_path)
formatted_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sample', index=False)
writer.save()
print("File saved successfully:", output_file_path)
```